# Which these conditional has a better performance in php?

Tags: php

I think the first approach has a better performance.

```
<?php if(cond) { $var = 'v1'; } else { $var = 'v2'; } ?>
```

or

```
<?php $var = (cond)?'v1':'v2'; ?>
```

thanks.

EDIT: i mean about server performance like wasting less ram ...

Comment: PHP is extremely slow and PHP code is not transferred to the client, micro-optimizations like that won't even give you a 0.0001ms advantage running Apache on a K6-II for sure. Use the code which you consider more maintainable and readable.

Comment: Optimization is good. Paranoid about optimization is bad.

Comment: * [PHP freshmen wants to optimize...](http://qkme.me/35ksv1)

Answer (score 4):

No performance difference. Only readability issues. Stop giving so much importance to such tiny details and focus on the bigger picture!

Answer (score 2):

For those of you curious just how little a difference there is:

After 10 million iterations on a G5 the if/else statement takes 15.987 seconds while the ternary takes 17.953.

That is a difference of 1.61 over 10 million iterations or .161 microseconds.

Comment: That's interesting. I would have imagined it to be the other way... +1 just for posting some numbers. However, from the posted numbers it appears to be a 11% increase, which might lead some to believe it should be used exclusively "for performance" even if the difference will decrease to [effectively] nothing *when* part of a larger context. (Microbenchmarks can be very misleading.)

Comment: You are right 11% seems like a lot and people should not be misled. The reason it is negligible is because we are talking about 11% of 1.59 microseconds which could easily be the error margin in the test itself. An 11% increase on an operation that takes an hour would be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no noticeable difference between the two whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that they run at exactly the same speed although the the first may take more time to parse by an unbelievably small margin. Is your app running slow? I suppose your bottleneck may be elsewhere.